# DFS - How to check out a virtual doc with "Root, and Read-only descendants"

Tags: documentum

When using Webtop to checkout a virtual document, there is an option "Root, and Read-only descendants".  How to achieve the same functionality using Documentum Foundation Services (DFS)?

Thanks,

Ning